# When should I use pyspark saveAsTable?

Tags: python, pyspark

In pyspark I can save using `saveAsTable()`:

```
  df = spark.read.parquet('input') \
    .write \
    .format('parquet') \
    .saveAsTable('output')
```

or without it:

```
  df = spark.read.parquet('input') \
    .write \
    .parquet('output')
```

What is the difference between them?